# Could not find Shared.jar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, jar

I've been searching for my issue but I didn't find any results. On the beginning of my new projects, an error pops up and says 'could not find shared.jar' and the layouts don't work. can you help me on this??

Comment: please. anyone? :(

Comment: There should be a `shared.jar` within the subdirectory of your Android Studio instalation: `plugins\android\lib\shared.jar`. If not reinstall Android Studio.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much